# Present a modalview in a tabbar app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modal-view

I have a tabbar project, but when the app loads, it should display a modal view with a login screen. I do 
`selfcareViewController *selfcareView = [[selfcareViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:selfcareView animated:YES];`

in the first view controller of the tabbar. But it doesn't load anything.

Comment: try [tabbar presentModalViewController...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try presenting the modal view controller from the UITabbarController itself.